# Google Play Games Leaderboard not opening

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

Trying to create a leaderboard via CloudOnce for android in my unity game. In test the leaderboard works but when I build it, it doesn't. The leaderboard won't open, stuck on this problem for a couple of days now..

Tried force resolving the play services.
Renaming the maps to remove special characters.
Deleting and reinstalling the packages.

These are the errors i'm getting.

1. `[Play Games Plugin DLL] 04/10/19 20:02:53 +00:00 ERROR: Exception launching token request: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.games.bridge.TokenFragment`
2. ````
   at UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CheckException () [0x00091] in <07e4b01d268e49d9893add5a5bf8a7f1>:0 
   at UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CallStaticObjectMethod (System.IntPtr clazz, System.IntPtr methodID, UnityEngine.jvalue[] args) [0x00011] in <07e4b01d268e49d9893add5a5bf8a7f1>:0 
   at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject._CallStatic[ReturnType] (System.String methodName, System.Object[] args) [0x002d6] in <07e4b01d268e49d9893add5a5bf8a7f1>:0 
   at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject.CallStatic[ReturnType] (System.String methodName, System.Object[] args) [0x00001] in <07e4b01d268e49d9893add5a5bf8a7f1>:0 
   at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject.FindClass (System.String name) [0x0001d] in <07e4b01d268e49d9893add5a5bf8a7f1>:0 
   at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaClass._AndroidJavaClass (System.String className) [0x00012] in <07e4b01d268e49d9893add5a5bf8a7f1>:0 
   at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaClass..ctor (System.String className) [0x00007] in <07e4b01d268e49d9893add5a5bf8a7f1>:0 
   at GooglePlayGames.Android.AndroidTokenClient.DoFetchToken (System.Boolean silent, System.Action`1[T] callback) [0x00016] in /Users/Username/Games/XXXXX/Assets/Extensions/GooglePlayGames/Platforms/Android/AndroidTokenClient.cs:151 ```
   ````

I believe its an auth problem but no idea how to fix it!

Comment: Using internal or gradle build?

Comment: Check if you are referencing `play-games-plugin-support.aar`...

Comment: Using cradle build, it says the internal build is deprecated so rated not use that. Just to be sure I tried an internal build, get the same results..

Comment: Gradle is fine, you should use it. Unity usually create it for you but you could tweak it. Check if `play-games-plugin-support.aar` is mentioned as dependency. Also check if you have that lib in folder hierarchy, somewhere Plugin\Android\Lib....

Comment: Thanks, i'll try it out. Post back the results!

Comment: I do believe I the ```play-games-plugin-support.aar``` is already add, just like this: ```implementation(name: 'com.google.games.gpgs-plugin-support-0.9.62', ext:'aar')``` correct me if I'm wrong :)